# Compactness of spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Which of the following metric spaces $X$ are compact?

(a) Let $S$ is an infinite set, let $X$ be $\{ f:S \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \mid \| f\|_\infty \leq 1 \}$ equipped with sup norm

$$\|f-g\|_\infty = \sup_{s\in S}|f(s)-g(s)|.$$

(b) $X = \{(x_1,x_2,...) \mid x_n \in [0,\frac{1}{n}] \}$ with $l^2$ norm

$$d(x,y)=\sqrt{\sum(x_i - y_i)^2}.$$

To clarify what I have tried for (b), here is my attempt. I believe that there is a slicker method.

*Proof.* Let $((x_n)^{(k)})_{k\geq1}$ be a sequence in $X$. Consider $((x_1)^{(k)})_{k\geq1}$, since $[0,1]$ is compact, there exists a convergent subsequence $((x_1)^{(k_1)})_{k_1\geq1}$ which converges to $x_1$. Now consider $((x_2)^{(k_1)})_{k_1\geq1}$, similarly there exists a convergent subsequence $((x_1)^{(k_2)})_{k_2\geq1}$ which converges to $x_2$. Iterate this process.

We claim that the following subsequence $((x_n)^{(k_l)})_{l\geq1}$

$$(x_n)^{(k_1=1)}, (x_n)^{(k_2=2)}, (x_n)^{(k_3=3)}, ...$$

of the original sequence $((x_n)^{(k)})_{k\geq1}$ converges to $(x_n)$. Let $\epsilon > 0$, let $N$ be large so that

$$\sum _{n=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} < \epsilon.$$

For $M$ large enough, for all $1 \leq i \leq N$,

\begin{alignat}{1}
  m \geq M
    &\implies |x_i^{(l_m)}-x_i|^2 < \frac{\epsilon}{i^2}\\
    &\implies \sum_{i=1}^N |x_i^{(l_m)}-x_i|^2 \ < 
      \ \sum_{i=1}^N\frac{\epsilon}{i^2}\ \leq \ \epsilon \frac{\pi^2}{6}\\
    &\implies \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_i^{(l_m)}-x_i|^2\ \leq \epsilon (\frac{\pi^2}{6} + 1).
\end{alignat}

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: OK, good work.  You can save a couple of lines using the dominated convergence theorem, but it's also good to do it directly.

Comment: But DCT concerns integrability of the limit function, not existence of a convergent subsequence?

Comment: DCT has as hypothesis pointwise convergence of  a sequence of functions and as conclusion $L^1$ convergence.  You can easily derive an $L^p$ version.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Hints:  If you can find an infinite subset $\{a_n\}$ in your metric space such that $d(a_n, a_m) = 1$ for $n \ne m$, then your space is not compact. For part (b) a famous theorem in measure/integration theory may be useful.

Edit: Your proof for part (b) looks fine to me.  You can avoid the estimates as follows:  by Tychonoff, or by your diagonal subsequence argument, there is a subsequence of your original sequence in $X$ that converges pointwise.  But every element in $X$ is bounded in absolute value by the $\ell^2$ sequence $(1/n)_{n \ge 0}$.   Hence by the dominated convergence theorem, pointwise convergence implies $\ell^2$ convergence. But your estimates are not difficult, and in my opinion it is better to do it directly when you can.

Comment: For (a) we use $f_n(x)=1$ if $x \geq n$ and $0$ otherwise?

Comment: That's the idea.  But note your infinite set $S$ is not necessarily countable and $x \ge n$ doesn't make sense.  Nevertheless, that's the right idea.

Comment: I see. For part (b), are you talking about Monotone Convergence Theorem?

Comment: You work it out.  There may be various successful approaches.

Comment: For part (b), my answer is that X is compact, but my proof is tedious. The idea is that $[0,1/n]$ is compact and so we keep picking "subsequences of subsequences". But I still want to learn your slick proof. I am guessing MCT or Dominated Convergence Theorem but I can't see how this applies?

Comment: For (b), topologists  will recognize the topology induced on $X$ as the Tychonoff product topology on $\prod_{n\in \Bbb N}[0,1/n] $ which, by the Tychonoff Theorem, is compact.  We can also show by elementary means,, without this theorem, that $X$ has no infinite closed discrete sub-space.